# Grails Change data base URL connection from session

Tags: grails

I need to change the url of data source using session or change current connection to new connection or build new data source at runtime (in my controller or service)

if any one can tell me another way exclude multi data source tell me

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like really ad-hoc, is this really what you want to do? Can't you just execute regular queries and filter data that way?

Comment: yes when ad-hoc but if my domain class name is User

User.get(1) //result from DB 1

...... after change connection 

User.get(1) //result from DB 2

Comment: Can you configure multiple DB sources in the DataSource.groovy and the use conditions in the controller to determine which data source to use?

Comment: ibaralf yes i can but i need to create new data source in controller or change current connection

Comment: You can have different data sources defined, but I'm not sure you can switch on the fly (=in a controller)

What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: mark I need to change current connection if i have multiple datasource i need change the default data base

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have an approach that's not the cleanest, but should work. If you get access to the `dataSource` Spring bean you can change its properties. You need to get it to close all pooled connections and then new connections will use the new settings.

You can get to the datasource using dependency injection like any bean, i.e. `def dataSourceUnproxied`. You have to use "dataSourceUnproxied" instead of "dataSource" to get at the real `DataSource`, not the transaction-aware proxy that Grails wraps the real one with.

Having done that you can change the url, username, etc. like this:

```
dataSourceUnproxied.url = 'some other url'
dataSourceUnproxied.username = 'some other username'
```

Then close it to force all connections to close, but reset the `closed` flag to trick it into re-connecting the next time `getConnection()` is called:

```
dataSourceUnproxied.close()
dataSourceUnproxied.closed = false
```

This is very specific to the pool implementation since the `DataSource` interface only has a few methods. This works with the `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` that Grails uses by default but if you're using a different pool implementation you'll need to look at its source for an equivalent approach.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426796/grails-make-the-connection-to-hibernate-change-dynamically i hope you can help me